# Обновление строки при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: java, jframe

В `JFrame` есть строка, значение которой нужно постоянно обновлять при нажатии на кнопку, но это не работает.

Как это реализовать?

*Button*:

```
    class Button extends JFrame() {

    JButton button;
    JTextArea text;

    Listining l = new Listining();

    public Button(String s) {
        super(s); //Вызываем исходник
        int a;
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        button = new JButton("Та самая кнопка");
        text = new JTextArea(a);
        add(button);
        add(text);
        button.addActionListener(l);
    }
}
```

*ActionListener*:

```
public class Listining implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
            if (e.getSource() == button) { 
                a++;
            }
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error, sorry.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _Добавил ActionListener_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try {
    if (e.getSource() == button) { 
        a++;
        text.setText(a);
    }
} catch(Exception ex) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error, sorry.");
}
```

Comment: **Ваш ответ не работает**

Comment: Ваш вопрос был - как при нажатии на кнопку обновлять значение в строке.
Код, который я привел, делает следующее
смотрит, нажата была кнопка button или нет.
Если нажата та кнопка, то инкрементим счетчик a, и далее записываем в поле текст полученное значение.
В чем не работает?

Comment: **Глубоко извиняюсь, сделал ошибку перед проверкой работоспособности, спасибо.